# Is every odd integer greater than $105$ the sum of two coprime composite numbers?

Tags: number-theory

> Can any odd integer greater than 105 be represented as the sum of two
>    coprime composite numbers?

The answer to this question conjectures that *any* integer greater than $210$ is the sum of two coprime composite numbers. [Numbers as sum of two relatively prime composite numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455165/numbers-as-sum-of-two-relatively-prime-composite-numbers)

Comment: Might have something to do with 105 = 3*5*7.

Comment: This question seems to be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455165/numbers-as-sum-of-two-relatively-prime-composite-numbers

Comment: I think I have proven that all integers $\geq 106$ can be written as sum of two coprime composite numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim:** For an odd integer $n\geq 107$, there exists an odd prime $p$ such that $p \not\mid n$ and $p^2+4\leq n$.

**Proof**: Assume the contrary. Then for all odd primes under $\sqrt{n-4}$, $p \mid n$. $$\prod_{p<\sqrt{n-4}}p | n$$

Now by Bertrand's postulate, there exists a prime in each of the intervals $[8,16),[16,32),\cdots, [2^k,2^{k+1})$, and also $3,5,7$.

We have $2^{k+1}\leq\sqrt{n-4} \implies k = \frac{1}{2}\log_2(n-4)-1$

For $n\geq 260$, we have $k \geq 3$

A lower bound we can achieve on the product of them will be

$$\prod_{p < \sqrt{n-4}}p \geq 3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot2^{3+4+\cdots+k}=\frac{105}{8}\cdot 2^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}\geq^* \frac{105}{8}\cdot 2^{2k-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{105}{8}\cdot 2^{\log_2(n-4)-2}=\frac{105(n-4)}{8}>n$$

And thus the produtc doesn't divide $n$, contraditcion.

For values $107 \leq n \leq 259$, $\sqrt{n-4}\geq 10$, and the product of odd primes under $n$ are $3\cdot5\cdot7=105$. Clearly one of $3,5,7$ doesn't divide $n$ unless $n=210$, for which $11$ doesn't divide $n$.

---

Then $p^2$ and $n-p^2$ are composite numbers and they're coprime. ($n-p^2$ is even and $\geq 4$)

Edit: Actually after rereading my "thing", I don't see any reason why this can't be applied to a even number - just replace $4$ with $9$.

Comment: The part $107 \leq n \leq 259$ sounds so stupid >:( i think it can be fixed/solved by getting a even better lower bound for the product of primes under $\sqrt{n-4}$. idk.

Comment: The number 105 comes from the fact that the odd primes under $\sqrt{101}$ is $3,5,7$, and $105$ is divisible by all of them. stupid number

Comment: Some prime paper for people interested: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807 Corollary 3.16 says that $\prod_{p \leq x} > e^{x(1-\frac{1}{\log(x)})}$, though this stupidly tight bound is not required here (I don't believe)

Comment: Should the lower bound on the product be $\displaystyle 3\cdot5\cdot2^{3+4+...+k}=\frac{15}{8}\cdot 2^{k(k+1)/2}$? Or, better still,  $\displaystyle 3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot2^{3+4+...+k}=\frac{105}{8}\cdot 2^{k(k+1)/2}$?

Comment: Ah, yes indeed. Thank you.